# require returns empty object when using browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a very simple module that I am bundling with Browserify.  I want to use that bundle both in the browser as well as in node.  In node, it works just fine if I `require` the non-bundled module; however, if I `require` the browserified bundle, `require` returns an empty object. Here's a reproduction:

Simple module

```
function Foo(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

Test script

```
var Foo = require("./foo"); // not bundled with Browserify
var Foob = require("./foob"); // bundled with Browserify

console.log("Foo =", Foo);
console.log("Foob =", Foob);
```

Executed thusly

```
browserify foo.js -o foob.js
node foo-test.js
```

Output

```
Foo = function Foo(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}
Foob = {}
```

You can see that `Foo` (the non-bundled version) is the expected function but `Foob` (the bundled version) is a sad and empty object.

So the question is why isn't the browserified module working in node?

**Clarification:**  I'm using browserify to bundle my webapp and I use its [paths options to simplify paths](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/issues/17) in my app's require statements and avoid relative path hell. However, I'm trying to use tap to do unit testing, but it doesn't seem to have a similar configuration feature. Because of this, trying to require non-bundled files when using tap causes everything to break.

Comment: You don't `require` a Browserify-ied bundle file

Comment: foob.js is bundled with browserify.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but you're not supposed to use `require` with an already bundled module.

Comment: Is it impossible then to use bundles built with browserify in node?

Comment: That's not the intended use of Browserify. Browserify was built to emulate Node's `require` but for browser environments. So to use Browserify within Node would be completely ass-backwards.

Comment: I see your point but I see no other way around it for my setup. I'm using browserify to bundle my webapp and I use its `paths` options to simplify paths in my app's require statements and avoid include path hell.  However, I'm trying to use tap to do unit testing, but it doesn't seem to have a similar configuration feature.  Because of this, trying to require non-bundled files when using tap causes everything to break.  I guess the real question should be is there a test runner/framework that has a similar `paths` option?

Comment: Yeah @benhowdle89 is right. browserify assumes no `require()` is available and overrides it. In `node`, you *want* it to do the default thing. Can you edit your post to explain in more detail your why you cannot just `require('./foob')` in your app? Isn't `foob.js` right here in the same directory?

Comment: To be more specific: I don't understand what the `paths` issue and "path hell" you are referring to are.

Comment: When I talk about the `paths` option, I am referring to this technique https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/issues/17. I am doing `require('./foob')` in my test script, but it returns an empty object instead of a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way around this.  The solution is to use browserify's `--standalone` option when bundling.  This will add the necessary module.exports statement in the bundled output.

Comment: Thank you for this. This is what solved it for me when creating an NPM client-side library.

Answer (score 0):

You want to nest browserify bundles. In this case, ensure that your nested bundles actually have `module.exports` defined.

For instance in the main file of your `foob.js` bundle, be sure to return a function you can use externally (using `module.exports`)